# Why does a keyboard have two Ctrl keys?

Tags: keyboard

As the question tells everything, why does keyboard have 2 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys.

As their function is same then why these keys are multiple on keyboard? Is there any specific reason or they are just for making typing easy?

Comment: Note that there are not 2 Alt keys. It's Alt and Alt Gr, and they fulfill different functions, already by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is purely for ease of typing.  The ctrl, alt, and shift keys are usually used in conjuction with another key.  So by pressing one of the keys with one hand, your other hand is free to press another key.

One interesting thing to note is that each of those keys are unique.  I.E. even though the left shift key and the right shift key will do the same thing by default, they have different [scancodes](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html).  This can allow you to assign something else to those keys using software.

Comment: To be more specific, to support touch typing.

Comment: Depending on your locale, these might not have identical functions. For example in de_DE the right Alt key (Alt Graph) can be used to type special characters, while the left Alt key functions as a normal alt.

Answer (score 0):

its for the just making the type easier like  in example it you want to use upper case on right side the right shift key make is faster and easier and near left side the left shift key 
there are many more example and like we never want to use the left alt with enter so the main purpose of this is making just keyboard easier to use

[image]

Comment: Oh goodness, I hope I never have to use a hardware keyboard like that!